# Sending data from Arduino BLE to Android , how to combine small chunks of received UART data in Android App

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am sending gps location data from the Arduino BLE to my android app as small chunks(less than 20bytes). I am  getting the data in my android app , but how can i combine the small chunks to a string.
This is the code in my arduino program to send the location data to android app.

```
            String msg = "lat:";
            msg += GPS.latitude;
            msg += ",";
            msg.toCharArray(sendBuffer, 20);
            ble.print("AT+BLEUARTTX=");
            ble.println(sendBuffer);

            String msg1 = "lon:";
            msg1 += GPS.longitude;
            msg1 += ",";
            msg1.toCharArray(sendBuffer, 20);
            ble.print("AT+BLEUARTTX=");
            ble.println(sendBuffer);

            String msg2 = "speed:";
            msg2 += GPS.speed;
            msg2.toCharArray(sendBuffer, 20);
            ble.print("AT+BLEUARTTX=");
            ble.println(sendBuffer);
```

And in my android app this is the code to get the UART data

```
if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE)) {
            final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);
            try {
               String receivedData = new String(txValue, "UTF-8");
               Log.i(TAG, "receivedData:" + receivedData);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
```

Please see my log, how i am getting the data.

```
I/ContentValues: receivedData:lat:28.907892,lon:45
I/ContentValues: receivedData:.789005,speed:0.02
```

Please , how can i get the latitude, longitude, speed as one string from the received data. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to accumulate received data in a field variable. Process substrings of accumulated data split by delimiter. 
Here is a sample code:

```
//Field variable 
String mReceivedData = "";    

if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE)) {
    final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);
    try {
           mReceivedData += new String(txValue, "UTF-8");
           int delim;
           while((delim = mReceivedData.indexOf('\n')) > -1) {
               String dataToProcess = mReceivedData.subString(0, delim);

               // Process the data
               Log.i(TAG, "dataToProcess:" + dataToProcess);

               mReceivedData = mReceivedData.subString(delim + 1);
           } 
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also it may be possible to properly format received data in UartService and then send it to your Activity.

Comment: @Suren, Thank you for the help.